# git - used wrong email for pushing to repo

Tags: git, github

For the past month, my local `git config --global user.email` did not match the email of my GitHub account, and so my pushes to GitHub were not show up as contributions, as per [GitHub's criteria for counting contributions](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile/).

I have corrected my email, and my pushes show up as contributions at this point forward, but still not for the past month when the email was wrong.

Is it possible for me to recover and retroactively apply those uncounted past commits/pushes toward my GitHub contributions record, or have those counts been lost forever?

Comment: Could you not only add that email to your github account? Otherwise, if you are the one managing the repo your could do interactive rebasing to change the mail of your incorrect commits and then force push. However, if you this repository is shared this will be creating a bunch of problems if someone else has code checked out from before you did so.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the committer and author identity using `git filter-branch`.  You will need to create an environment filter script.  GitHub has documentation on their [changing author info help page](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info/), but if you are the only committer, you can use a simpler script:

```
export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="My Name"
export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="my-email@example.com"
export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="My Name"
export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="my-email@example.com"
```

The standard caveats for modifying history apply, and this will only work well if nobody else is working on the same project.  You will need to push in a special way:

```
git push --force-with-lease <repository> <branch>
```

Answer (score 1):

I added a second email account in order to have two sets of contributions displayed in my GitHub profile.

**Go to Personal Settings > Emails and try adding the first email address so you have two email accounts.**

Having both email accounts in my GitHub Emails settings meant that I didn't have to change any of my history - it was a quick and easy change.